# What does n.d. mean when using panda series python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I am looking for the `max` value for a class `panda.core.series.Series` and it returns `n.d.` when I use the following code

```
rowMax = df.max(axis = 1)
```

**Question:** What does n.d. mean and how can I get an actual value? (My series is 20031 in length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try simulate your problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1','3','4'],
                   'B':['5','6','3'],
                   'E':['3','4', 3]})

print (df)
   A  B  E
0  1  5  3
1  3  6  4
2  4  3  3

a = df.max(axis=1)
print (a)
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
dtype: float64
```

It means your data are mixed - numeric with strings.

Solution is convert all data to numeric:

```
a = df.astype(int).max(axis=1)
print (a)
0    5
1    6
2    4
dtype: int32
```

Sometimes it is no possible, because non numeric data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['rr','3','4'],
                   'B':['5','6','3'],
                   'E':['3','4', 3]})

print (df)
    A  B  E
0  rr  5  3
1   3  6  4
2   4  3  3

a = df.astype(int).max(axis=1)
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'rr'

Then is possible use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
a = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
print (a)
     A  B  E
0  NaN  5  3
1  3.0  6  4
2  4.0  3  3

a = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).max(axis=1)
print (a)
0    5.0
1    6.0
2    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed a Series and not a Dataframe the `max` method should work without any argument.

```
s = pd.Series({'a' : 0., 'b' : 1., 'c' : 2.})
s.max()

> 2
```

Are you sure you are not dealing with a dataframe ?

Comment: It is a series but I took a closer look at the dataframe that it originally came from and there are many rows with `n.d.` values. I guess the bigger issue would be dealing with these rows. Any suggestions on how to skip or ignore these rows or should I post a new question on SO?

Comment: What is the dtype of the Series and are "n.d." string ?